# Expected distance of a stone thrown into a circular pond

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

A stone is thrown into a circular pond of radius 1 meter. Suppose the stone falls uniformly at random on the area of the pond. The expected distance of the stone from the center of the pond is:
A) $1/3$
B) $1/2$
C) $2/3$
D) $1/2^{1/2}$

**My Work:** Since we have been asked to calculated the expected distance of the stone from the center of the pond which is circular, I can call this distance a random variable $d$ and conclude that $d$ is uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1].
Expected value of a uniformly distributed random variable = $(a+b)/2$ where $a$ and $b$ are equal to $0$ & $1$ here respectively. 
So the answer should be $1/2$.
But the answer key says **C)** as the correct option. Can someone clarify where I went wrong, and how should one solve this?

Comment: Please do a reality check of your conclusion that the distance is uniformly distributed: is it plausible that positions within $\epsilon$ of the perimeter really are as likely as positions within $\epsilon$ of the center?

Comment: How did you "conclude that d is uniformly distributed over the interval [0,1]" ? Is the area of a circle proportional to its radius?  Is the radius of a circle proportional to its area?

Comment: If a point is uniform over a circular disk, the probability of it falling inside a region A entirely within the disk is proportional to the area of A. What's the fraction of the area within a distance of $\frac12$ from the center? (Do you see how this contradicts your thinking about the distance being uniform?)

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.